# Extract a line if the first field contains a dot

Tags: command-line, text-processing

The actual data is:

```
Dolibarr                      techpubl        http://techpublications.org/erp
tekstilworks.com              WordPress       tekstilw
wbq.dandydesigns.co         WordPress       cbeqte
WordPress                     cbeqte          http://wbq.dandydesigns.co
WordPress                     cbeqte          http://qbd.dandydesigns.co
WordPress                     cbeqte          http://uqdq.dandydesigns.co
dandydesigns.co               WordPress     cbeqte
stunlockers.info              WordPress         nmmuop
```

What I want to get:

```
 tekstilworks.com              WordPress       tekstilw
 wbq.dandydesigns.co         WordPress       cbeqte
 dandydesigns.co               WordPress     cbeqte
 stunlockers.info              WordPress         nmmuop
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /\./' input-file-here
```

The period in the awk expression has to be escaped with a backslash so that it's not treated as a regular expression syntax.

Comment: the `{print}` statement is not mandatory as the default behavior in awk would be print.

Answer (score 5):

Using `grep` to match `.` in the first field:

```
grep '^[^[:blank:]]*\.' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
Dolibarr                      techpubl        http://techpublications.org/erp
tekstilworks.com              WordPress       tekstilw
wbq.dandydesigns.co         WordPress       cbeqte
WordPress                     cbeqte          http://wbq.dandydesigns.co
WordPress                     cbeqte          http://qbd.dandydesigns.co
WordPress                     cbeqte          http://uqdq.dandydesigns.co
dandydesigns.co               WordPress     cbeqte
stunlockers.info              WordPress         nmmuop

$ grep '^[^[:blank:]]*\.' file.txt
tekstilworks.com              WordPress       tekstilw
wbq.dandydesigns.co         WordPress       cbeqte
dandydesigns.co               WordPress     cbeqte
stunlockers.info              WordPress         nmmuop
```

Comment: The same search works here: `sed -n '/^[^[:blank:]]*\./p' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

just for fun, bash

```
(set -f; while IFS= read -r line; do set -- $line; [[ $1 == *.* ]] && echo "$line"; done) <filename
```